# How to determine types of subprograms in Oracle Package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This is best explained with an example. Given the below database objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PACKAGE IS

  PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE;
  FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN NUMBER;

END TEST_PACKAGE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE IS

  PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE IS
  BEGIN
    NULL;
  END;

  FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN NULL;
  END;

END TEST_PACKAGE;
/
```

If we query **USER_PROCEDURES** for the unpackaged subprograms, we get their types reported in the **OBJECT_TYPE** column:

[image]

However if we query for the subprograms in the package, we only get an **OBJECT_TYPE** of **PACKAGE**, which is not especially useful:

[image]

Is it possible to query to find out the actual types without doing something like digging through **USER_SOURCE**? I've looked through the data dictionary but found nothing useful.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar idea to @collapsar, but using the argument position to differentiate between a procedure and a function. A function has an (unnamed) argument in position zero, in addition to any formal parameters which start at position one. Procedures don't have the position zero argument.

```
select up.object_name, up.procedure_name,
  case ua.position when 0 then 'FUNCTION' else 'PROCEDURE' end as type
from user_procedures up
left join user_arguments ua
on ua.object_id = up.object_id
and ua.subprogram_id = up.subprogram_id
and position = 0
where up.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
and up.object_name = 'TEST_PACKAGE'
and up.procedure_name is not null;

OBJECT_NAME                    PROCEDURE_NAME                 TYPE    
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------
TEST_PACKAGE                   TEST_FUNCTION                  FUNCTION 
TEST_PACKAGE                   TEST_PROCEDURE                 PROCEDURE
```

Comment: Deleted my comments as the solution provided is very accurate. Thanks

Comment: Works, great. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You may identify package functions and procedures by using the `all_procedures` view, examining the data on the method's arguments as it is stored in the data dictionary for a return value:

```
    SELECT p.object_name
         , p.procedure_name
         , CASE WHEN a.object_id IS NULL THEN 'PROCEDURE' ELSE 'FUNCTION' END ptype
      FROM all_procedures p
 LEFT JOIN all_arguments  a ON (
                                     a.object_id     = p.object_id
                                 AND a.subprogram_id = p.subprogram_id
                                 AND a.data_level    = 0
                                 AND a.argument_name IS NULL
                               )
     WHERE p.object_name IS NOT NULL
         ;
```